# Trigger callback if time expires without being 'kicked' first

Tags: c, linux, timer, posix, embedded-linux

I have a Linux application that needs to perform an action after 5 seconds if the same application doesn't 'kick' or reset the 5 second timer before it expires. What mechanism is best for this?

I was considering using `alarm(5)` and 'kick' it with `alarm(5)` when needed but I was hoping to avoid needing to handle a `SIGALRM`.

I was reading up on `timer_create()` as well but I'm not seeing a way to configure a callback or reset the timer.

I'm looking for something similar to a watchdog timer but within my application only.

Comment: There's some good suggestions in [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736143/425458) on how to structure a multithreaded C program that acts on a timer. I don't think it's quite the same as what you're trying to do, but you'll probably have to post some more details on your program's current design/architecture to get any more specific suggestions.

Comment: `SIGALRM` would be my first choice. Why avoid it?